# Improving Azure DevOps npm build speed?

Tags: npm, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

How can I "economically" improve the npm build speeds in Azure DevOps? They take 3x longer than on my local machine.  I'm using the free tier.  I have read that we should be able to cache the npm modules somehow, but I can't find a good example (and am not clear if this ability requires a private build server or a paid DevOps or both?).

Is anyone successfully doing this?  If so, can you pls show me the yaml and explain where the modules cache would be kept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want caching of NPM modules, you'll need to use a private agent. You'll get that automatically, as private agents cache everything between builds.

Some other options:

- Setting up an artifacts feed with an upstream source to NPM may help somewhat, since the packages will be cached in the artifacts feed which is "closer" to the hosted agents from a networking perspective and may restore a bit faster.
- You can put `node_modules` into source control, which isn't a great option because of the size and frequency with which it changes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  Is a private agent basically a VM that I supply?  That's where I ran into push back from IT as they said an adequate Windows VM would be about $8k/year.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is effectively building on @daniel-mann original point - you want a [Self-hosted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops#install) agent.

IMHO $8k/year seems like a pretty extreme number for what is effectively a build server, but it ultimately depends on build throughput.

You are partially correct in your comment - the agent runs as a process/service on a machine (VM/bare-metal/etc).  The agent can be downloaded right from the settings in Azure DevOps Collection Settings and installation and configuration steps are provided.

[image]

[image]

You can double check prerequisites for [Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-linux?view=azure-devops), [macOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-osx?view=azure-devops) and [Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops) agents.

Additionally, to avoid bottle-necking builds / release (as they use the same agents) you can configure multiple agents (system resources permitting).  As you can see from the screenshot, we have 4 which works well for us.

Comment: This is very helpful.  They did mention that a "burstable" server was an option and would be less, but they didn't sound like it would be a lot less.  Thanks for the info!